# Google maps - window.initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

getting the above error when trying to load my map. Currently no map is displaying, and can't seem to find an answer anywhere! Any help would be greatly appreciated! My js code is as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "/js/jquery-1.11.2.js">
                        var map = null;
                        var iLoadPoints = 0;

                        function initialize() {
                            var mapOptions = {
                                center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: -6.284874},
                                zoom: 13
                            };
                            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                    mapOptions);


                             jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                                $.getJSON('/markers/json', function (data) {


                                    var locations = JSON.parse(data);

                                    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                                        addMarker(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        }


                        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
                            iLoadPoints += 1;
                            if (iLoadPoints === 2) {
                                initialize();
                            }
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
                            iLoadPoints += 1;
                            if (iLoadPoints === 2) {
                                initialize();
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery(..)ready function is inside the initialize function. and you don't call the initialize function.  this is wrong. It can't work.

I have comment  the part dependent form your configuration and added the call to the initialize function for a brief test.  (see below)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "/js/jquery-1.11.2.js">
                   var map = null;
                    var iLoadPoints = 0;

                    function initialize(){
                        var mapOptions = {
                            center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: -6.284874},
                            zoom: 13
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

                         jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/*                                $.getJSON('/markers/json', function (data) {

                                var locations = JSON.parse(data);
                                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                                    addMarker(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng);
                                }
                            });*/
                        });

                    }


/*                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
                        iLoadPoints += 1;
                        if (iLoadPoints === 2) {
                            initialize();
                        }
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
                        iLoadPoints += 1;
                        if (iLoadPoints === 2) {
                            initialize();
                        }
                    });*/

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

I think you must redesign your app.. movinge the part in jQuery..... function in a proper aree o function inside the initialize() function.

Comment: but surely I am calling initialize in either addListenertOnce or addDomListener??

Comment: In tests that I have made the initialize function was not called (I not  have available the same environment as you do), probably in your code, for reasons that I can not occur, the initialize function was not claimed and then the map could not appear . Check well your initialization logic.